# zsh - run gpustat command after login

Tags: ssh, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I am trying to execute the [gpustat](https://github.com/wookayin/gpustat) command after SSHing into a remote server.

I am using z-shell + oh-my-zsh.

I put the gpustat command into my .zshrc file.

However, after logging in, I get the error message:

```
command not found: gpustat
```

What I find confusing is that when I source the .zshrc file, the gpustat command is executed and works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to run `gpustat` in your `.zshrc` file *before* it has been added to your `$path`. My guess is that its added to your path somewhere later in your `.zshrc`, which would explain why it works when you source your `.zshrc` file manually: At that point, your whole `.zshrc` file has already been sourced once and `gpustat` has been added to your `$path` at that point.